# How to fix the ansible playbook error "Unsupported parameters for (systemd) module: enable Supported parameters?

Tags: ansible, devops

I am trying to install Apache 2, PHP on Ubuntu machine using the ansible-playbook.
I am getting the following error

```
[Error after executing playbook][1]

fatal: [18.220.215.181]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (systemd) module: enable Supported parameters include: daemon_reexec, daemon_reload, enabled, force, masked, name, no_block, scope, state, user"}
```

The ansible playbook is as follows

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: Chenking ping
    ping:
  - name: Update packages
    apt:
      name: apache2
      update_cache: yes
      state: present
  - name: restart apache2 server
    service:
      name: apache2
      enable: yes
      state: restarted
  - name: install php module
    apt:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      state: present
    with_items:
     - php
     - libapache2-mod-php5
     - php-mcrypt
     - php-mysql
  - name: restart apache2 afetr restart
    service:
      name: apache2
      enable: yes
      state: restarted
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and Ansible? and can you post the whole error message, as it's not clear on what task the error happens.

Comment: Ubuntu version is 18 and ansible version is 2.8, For error message click on hyperlink "Error after executing playbook" in above question i have attached the error message in form of image

Answer (score 3):

The right parameter is `enabled` (not `enable`) in your `service` tasks.

```
  - name: restart apache2 afetr restart
    service:
      name: apache2
      enabled: yes
      state: restarted
```

Answer (score 0):

Change "enabled" task containing service module.

```
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: Chenking ping
    ping:
  - name: Update packages
    apt:
      name: apache2
      update_cache: yes
      state: present
  - name: restart apache2 server
    service:
      name: apache2
      enabled: yes
      state: restarted
  - name: install php module
    apt:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      state: present
    with_items:
     - php
     - libapache2-mod-php5
     - php-mcrypt
     - php-mysql
```

I think last task is not required.